# Affiliate Webgains with VirtueMart

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart, affiliate

Actually i use joomla with virtuemart and i want add in the thank´s page the code of WebGains , the problem it´s the code never connect right with WebGains

The code it´s javascript and call url of WebGains

```
<!-- <webgains tracking code> -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var wgOrderReference = "myorderreference";
var wgOrderValue = "0";
var wgEventID = 1341771;
var wgComment = "";
var wgLang = "es_ES";
var wgsLang = "javascript-client";
var wgVersion = "1.2";
var wgProgramID = 73451;
var wgSubDomain = "track";
var wgCheckSum = "";
var wgItems = "";
var wgVoucherCode = "";
var wgCustomerID = "";

if(location.protocol.toLowerCase() == "https:") wgProtocol="https";
else wgProtocol = "http";

wgUri = wgProtocol + "://" + wgSubDomain + ".webgains.com/transaction.html" + "?wgver=" + wgVersion + "&wgprotocol=" + wgProtocol + "&wgsubdomain=" + wgSubDomain + "&wgslang=" + wgsLang + "&wglang=" + wgLang + "&wgprogramid=" + wgProgramID + "&wgeventid=" + wgEventID + "&wgvalue=" + wgOrderValue + "&wgchecksum=" + wgCheckSum + "&wgorderreference="  + wgOrderReference + "&wgcomment=" + escape(wgComment) + "&wglocation=" + escape(document.referrer) + "&wgitems=" + escape(wgItems) + "&wgcustomerid=" + escape(wgCustomerID) + "&wgvouchercode=" + escape(wgVoucherCode);
document.write('<sc'+'ript language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript" src="'+wgUri+'"></sc'+'ript>');

</script>
<noscript>
<img src="http://track.webgains.com/transaction.html?wgver=1.2&wgprogramid=7401&wgrs=1&wgvalue=0&wgeventid=11771&wgorderreference=myorderreference&wgitems=&wgvouchercode=&wgcustomerid=" alt="" />
</noscript>
<!-- </webgains tracking code> -->
```

I get values of order id and total price from db and right , but the code from WebGains no show when i gon into admin for affiliate no show the payments or products , etc

If you can help me thank´s !!!

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your above example of the tracking code I can see that there are a few issues with this and that it why this will not be tracking correctly.

I can see the program ID for your 'CDaudiophile' program on the Spanish platform is 7401, which is set correctly in the NoScript tag. However, this is incorrect in the Script tag. Please set the wgProgramID in the script tag to 7401. This variable will not change.

The wgOrderReference variable needs to be set to a unique reference number for that transaction, this needs to be set in the Script tags and the NoScript tag.

The wgOrderValue variable in the Script tag and the wgValue variable in the NoScript tag needs to be set to the value of the transaction which you want to pay commission calculated on. Therefore, if you do not want to pay commission including the VAT and shipping of the transaction then these need to be removed from the total value before you pass the value in these variables to Webgains.

Your EventID is 11771 which relates to the 10% commission which you want to pay to affiliates. This EventID will not change unless you introduce further commission types. This again needs to be set in the Script and NoScript tags, I can see that this is not currently set correctly in the Script tag.

If a voucher code is used in the transaction then the wgVoucher code variable needs to be populated with the voucher code used. If no voucher code was used in the  transaction then please leave this variable blank.

Please make sure that you set all of these variables in both the Script tags and the NoScript tags.

Please feel free to contact me directly at acorby@webgains.com or email support for the Spanish Webgains platform at support@webgains.es

I hope this helps, please let me know if you have any further questions.